# c# record without curly brackets

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

I noticed by chance that the following code compiles (VS2022preview , c#10):

```
record R {
  public R() {}
  int I;
}

record B : R; // no curly brackets !
```

(see: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+tJQCYAIBKuA3gLABQuluAAgMwEAUAlMQL7lW4CWAdgC64AkgG5y7MuUzQ8AIVwgCwoA===)

I am curious how does this work without curly brackets for `B` ? is this in the standard ?

(this does not work if I change the record to class)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records See the definition of `record_body`

Comment: records without curly braces have been a thing for ages: `record Person(string Name, int Age)` ?

Comment: thanks @EmanuelVintilă can you post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the C# language specification for records https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records, the `record_body` clause is specified as

```
record_body
    : '{' class_member_declaration* '}' ';'?
    | ';'
    ;
```

Therefore, the curly braces may be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records

Pretty much what documentation says. C# 9.0 introduced many such changes. Top level program file, top level namespace declaration etc where they got rid of mandatory curly braces.